# Generic method in property write

Tags: delphi

I came up with the following for an easy to expand ["bit bucket"](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bit-bucket.html):

```pascal
unit BitBucket;

interface

type TBitBucket = class
private
  class procedure ThrowAway<T>(value: T); static;
public
  class property Integer: Integer write ThrowAway;
  class property String_: String write ThrowAway;
  class property Extended: Extended write ThrowAway;
  class property Boolean: Boolean write ThrowAway;
end;

implementation

class procedure TBitBucket.ThrowAway<T>(value: T);
begin
end;

end.
```

However, although there's no squiggly underlines in the IDE, it won't compile, with the following errors:

> [dcc32 Error] BitBucket.pas(9): E2008 Incompatible types
> [dcc32 Error] BitBucket.pas(10): E2008 Incompatible types
> [dcc32 Error] BitBucket.pas(11): E2008 Incompatible types
> [dcc32 Error] BitBucket.pas(12): E2008 Incompatible types

Is there a trick I'm missing that will make this compile?  I've tried specifying the generic type argument to `ThrowAway`, but that causes even more errors.  The obvious alternative is to write a `ThrowAway` method for every type, but that would quickly lead to a lot of code to do effectively nothing.

---

For those wondering why, in delphi, you can use a compiler switch to prevent use of functions without assigning their return value for compatibility with older code. With a BitBucket you can say `BitBucket.Integer := FunctionThatHasSideEffectsAndReturnsAnInteger(...);`, without having to create a new variable.  I also think it's just funny.

Comment: Delphi generics are much more restricted than its C++ counterpart. In any case, discarding a function's result is perfectly valid. The switch you are talking about is on by default.

Comment: Quick but ugly and rather stupid solution: `procedure ThrowAway(const X: Variant);
begin
end;`

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Using `const X` or `const X: Variant` in the argument list just leads to the same errors.

Comment: `const X` doesn't work, but `const X: Variant` works. https://privat.rejbrand.se/ThrowAway.pas

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, but that's not really using the same bitbucket analogue.  I'm trying to discover features of classes and properties.  Incidentally, I was working in RAD Studio 10.2 previously, doing the same under 10.4 does give the code red squiggles.

Comment: You can also have a global variable `var BitBucket: Variant`... You are right about the squiggles issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a generic with a variant. You need something like this:

```
unit BitBucket;

interface

type 
  TBitBucket<T> = class
  private
    class procedure ThrowAway(const Value: T); static;
    class var FVar: T;
  public
    class property MyProperty: T read FVar write ThrowAway;
  end;

implementation

class procedure TBitBucket<T>.ThrowAway(const Value: T);
begin
  FVar := Value;
end;

end.
```

The type is not decided until runtime when you access it i.e

```
TBitBucket<Integer>.MyProperty := 2;
```

Comment: (1) Not to be rude, but it seems like you are even more confused about the terminology, since you mention "variants" but don't use any variant at any place in your code. (2) Although your approach is valid, it can be greatly simplified, since you can remove the `FVar` class var altogether and let the `ThrowAway` method's body be empty. Also, you don't need to create an instance of the class, since you only use `class` members. `TBitBucket<Integer>.MyProperty := Test();` etc.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - I think Tav is referring to the fact that the OP is using a variant.

Comment: @Dsm: But the OP isn't using variants either...

Comment: I'm referring to the fact that OP's code seems to want Generics to work like variants, and they won't.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest solution i could come up with

```
type TBitBucket = class
  class var ThrowAway: variant;
end;
```

Usage

```
type test = class
  procedure Test;
end;


implementation

{ test }

procedure test.Test;
begin
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := 'AString';
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := 1;
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := 1.1234;
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := true;
end;
```

**Tvalue example**

And here a example with TValue instead from system.RTTI allowing to put objects into the bucket

```
type TBitBucket = class
  class var ThrowAway: Tvalue;
end;

type test = class
  procedure Test;
end;


implementation

{ test }

procedure test.Test;
begin
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := 'AString';
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := 1;
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := 1.1234;
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := true;
  TBitBucket.ThrowAway := TObject.Create;
end;
```